# F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:522] Check failed

Tags: tensorflow

I am training my model in tensorflow. After some iterations, I get following exception:

F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:522] Check failed: cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor(handle_.get(), elem_type, nd, dims.data(), strides.data()) == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (3 vs. 0)batch_descriptor: {count: 1 feature_map_count: 1088 spatial: 63 0  value_min: 0.000000 value_max: 0.000000 layout: BatchDepthYX}

Issue is not with cuda library as same code works for other data-sets. What can be the reason of it ?

Comment: Issue was image dimensions after resizing. This may help someone.

Comment: Were the dimensions too small? Thanks

Comment: hi Pervaiz, I'm facing the same issue. Could you please share how you fix it? thanks

Comment: Do check the input dimension, if it is smaller than actual input, try to increase the input dimension to avoid this error. Thanks